# How to hide a menu from users belonging in a user group

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Currently working on Joomla 3.2
I have created a user group called student and I want to hide different menu items from user of this group after logging in.
How to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial, should help ;)
http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_hide_something_from_logged_in_users%3F